# Should I get Enlightened badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, enlightened-badge

Today I've got 10 upvotes for an answer. Answer was a first answer in the question. I got an *Nice Answer* badge for this, but no *Enlightened* badge.

Shouldn't I get both?
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449351/linq-approach-to-this-code/3449365#3449365) is my answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will at earliest come when the grace period of the last vote (the time wherein the user can undo the vote) has expired. As far as I know, the grace period is 5 minutes. So at earliest 5 minutes after the last vote you should get it. At least, have patience for about 24 hours. There might be some cronjob responsible for rewarding the particular badge(s).

Comment: 2 days is actually the generally given time span for the rarer badges (the most often citation being Epic/Legendary). I recommend 48 hours over 24 hours, especially given the example from Juan Manuel I mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: It took 26 minutes for me to get one after I got the final upvote.