# Why does it still show that I have 7 silver badges?

Tags: bug, badges

Five hours ago, [I earned the Enlightened badge on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened?userid=1064099), which is my eighth silver badge. However, on my profile page and my posts, [it still shows that I have only 7 silver badges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1064099/mathlander?tab=profile) What is happening here?

(Normally, it takes a few minutes.)

Comment: For your information, the 8 silver badges that I have on Math Stack Exchange are Enlightened, Good Question, Deputy, Strunk & White, Reviewer, Enthusiast, Necromancer, and Civic Duty.

Comment: yeah, I can see it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1064099/mathlander?tab=badges&sort=recent). On that page it says 38 badges, but what it really means is 38 "unique" badges. Which is correct...

Comment: @00001H I gave a link to the 7 silver badges stat.

Comment: i know, the main profile page.

Comment: Also it shows 7 badges [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/24418759/mathlander?tab=accounts).
https://ibb.co/gyJ0MGj

Comment: Its probably caching.

Comment: [Probably](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/). *Comment might be not-up-to-date due to caching.

Comment: WAIT-- [It's fixed](https://ibb.co/Bft9w3y).

Comment: Why did it take so long to cache?

Comment: "Normally, it takes a few minutes" - that's plain and utterly wrong. It takes up to **one full day** for all the caches to synchronize, e.g. slowest to update is the network profile. It's currently broken, but when it worked, it synched the badges daily from what I remember.

Comment: You can have slow loading pages that are always accurate to the second, but are always slow even when none of the underlying data changes, or you can have eventual consistency where page loads are fast because they rely on the fact that, most of the time, an underlying change hasn't happened. The network is optimized for the latter scenario, and various caches are (a) on different schedules and (b) take varying amounts of time to populate. Some badges are particularly thorny because the variance in _complexity_ and _computation_ is huge.

Comment: Related: *[Should I get Enlightened badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60316/)* (*"at earliest 5 minutes after the last vote you should get it. At least, have patience for about 24 hours"*) and *[Missing Enlightened badge after 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363313/)* (*"The "within 24 hours" thing is true in most cases, but not technically correct anymore."*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fixed now, it was probably because the caches didn't catch up.

Related:
[this video explaining caching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY_2gElt3SA),
and [this website](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: Why did it take so long to cache?

Comment: Well, we don't know how SE's servers work, so I can only speculate the servers are either overloaded(or had poor networking) or it was a programming bug(or a nasty intended feature) in the server code. Or, some caches that should've updated are not, probably due to maintenance reasons.

Comment: @mathlander It's not a high-priority process to get those badges to show up. As long as they arrive within 24h, is there really an issue?

Comment: similar with being awarded bounty rep.

Comment: @starball no? Reputation gain is immediate. Do you have any source claiming otherwise?